# SWIFT: Array mismatch issue when attempting to display checkmarks in a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This seems like a fairly unique problem, and I'm hoping someone can provide some insight or a potential solution. I'm attempting to create a RSVP app for a wedding. Currently, when a guest signs in and accesses the RSVP screen, they are presented with invited family member for each of the events (see below):

[image]

The checkmarks you see in the screenshot above were manually entered (i.e. not retrieved from the database). I'm currently attempting to retrieve the true / false values for each event that each guest is invited (or not invited) to, and place a checkmark beside their name if the guest is invited. Here is a screenshot of the Parse database -

[image]

Guest names for each event have been populated in the tableView using "objectArray" -

[image]

Here's what I'm retrieving from the (\event)RSVP database, and storing it in the "checked" array:

[image]

Essentially, the first four values are for "Guest 1", the next four for "Guest 2", etc., which results in a checkmark being displayed for the wrong guests (the two arrays seem to be mismatched - one which sorts key : value on event, and the other being an ordered list of each guests RSVP status).

I think there are two potential solutions here: 
1) Create the "checked" array in the same order as "objectArray"
2) Find a way to display the checkmarks in the correct row in cellForRowAtIndexPath

If anyone can provide a simple solution or explanation, it would be really helpful. Thanks! Below is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class RSVPTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var checked = [Bool]()
var guestList = [String : [String]]()
let eventList = ["Hindu", "Reception", "Sangeet", "Tibetan"]

struct Objects {

    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
}

var objectArray = [Objects]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for event in eventList { guestList[event] = [String]() }

    let query = PFQuery(className:"GuestList")
    query.whereKey("Family", equalTo: "Family1")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let family = objects {

                for guest in family {

                    for event in self.eventList {

                        if let RSVP = guest.valueForKey("\(event)RSVP") as? Bool {

                            self.checked.append(guest.valueForKey("\(event)RSVP") as! Bool)

                        }

                        if let invited = guest.valueForKey("\(event)Invite") as? Bool {

                            if invited {
                            self.guestList[event]!.append(guest.valueForKey("GuestName") as! String)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (key, value) in self.guestList {
                    self.objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
                }

                //Reload Table View!
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print(self.checked)
                print(self.objectArray)

            }
        } else {
            print(error)
        }

    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return objectArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return objectArray[section].sectionName
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    /*

    Check Mark Code Required

    */

    cell.textLabel?.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {

        /*

        Check Mark Code Required

        */
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark

    }
}
}
```

**UPDATE:** Based on the values in Parse, the "Sangeet" column is the only one with "true" values, which means that the guests listed under the "Sangeet" section in the table should have checkmarks (no one else).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if self.checked[indexPath.section*tableView.numberOfSections+indexPath.row]{
       cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }else{
       cell.accessoryType = .None
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  The code you provided didn't work exactly as I wanted.  What's supposed to happen is that all guests invited to the "Sangeet" event should have a checkmark beside it (because all the database items under the SangeetRSVP column are 'true').  I've added a screenshot of the output in my original post.  Thanks.

Comment: That's not what you said in the post. Remember: "Essentially, the first four values are for "Guest 1", the next four for "Guest 2", etc., which results in a checkmark being displayed for the wrong guests (the two arrays seem to be mismatched - one which sorts key : value on event, and the other being an ordered list of each guests RSVP status)." The code works for the case you describe not the screen shots you posted. Which is it?

Comment: Try printing objects so we can see what's coming down from the server then we can make some classes that matche those objects.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of where the checkmarks need to be placed.  I'm having an issue using the following array to place the checkmarks in the right cells: [false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false].  The first four values in the array are for "Guest 1" across all events (the third value "true", is "SangeetRSVP").  Because the guestList dictionary is sorted by event, I need a solution which sorts the "checked" ordered array by event as well, and not guest.